# Sending email onEdit with the row data embedded into email in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a google script that when a person changes a column to "Approved" it sends an email out that grabs the cell that was changed.  However, I am not a expert scripter at all and am having a hard time in figuring out how to get the script to call the information from the actual row into the email either.

Here is my script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var rowData = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();getValue();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "test@sendemail.com";
  var message = '';
  if(cellvalue === 'Approved'){ 
    message = 'Cell ' + cell + ' ' + ' ' + rowData + ' was changed to Approved.';
    var subject = 'Cell Changed to Approved in Interns List';
    var body = message;
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
   }
 }
```

I couldnt find any solution thats been done already that would include the entire row that was triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var rowData = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].join(',');
  var recipients = "test@sendemail.com";
  var message = '';
  if(e.value == 'Approved'){ 
    message = 'Cell ' + e.range.getA1Notation() + ' ' + ' ' + rowData + ' was changed to Approved.';
    var subject = 'Cell Changed to Approved in Interns List';
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, message);
   }
 }
```

Comment: One more question for you.  If i wanted to get specific columns would i need to change the getValues?

Comment: Yes. I think you could add a `map(function(r){return [r[x],r[y].... ]}`

Comment: Forgive me, but how would i add that into the code?

Comment: Cooper - I have added variables   var client = rowData[0][0];
  var teaID = rowData[0][2]; to grab that data from the const variable and it only returns a "Cell E5   Dundefined was changed to Approved."  So it returned the first letter in my sheet but not the entire column data with was "Edward"

Comment: If you don’t get up you’ll figure out what you need to do

Comment: Ive been scouring the net and have not found anything that has worked, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Quit scouring and start reading and understanding the documentation.